# Flex/AIR Mobile: DateSpinner Component Performance Issues

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flexbuilder

I am using FB 4.6/AIR to develop a Mobile App for Android. I have spent the better part of an evening narrowing down why my View is taking so long to load. Low and behold I discovered that it is the DateSpinner component. I have tested it on a Galaxy SII as well as a Galaxy Nexus and both performance is identical.... slow. Additionally, I tweaked/simplified [Devgirl's DateSpinner example](http://devgirl.org/2011/11/17/flex-mobile-development-datespinner-sample-with-source/) to see if I would get the same results as I did with my APP and I did. I posted the the project file/FXP [here](https://www.box.com/s/0ef3f21eb0ea70f579b3)

Thanks, in advance.

Edit: Added Code

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="DateSpinner Sample">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import spark.components.calendarClasses.DateSelectorDisplayMode;
    ]]>
</fx:Script> 

<s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle">
</s:HGroup>
<s:Label text="{dt.selectedDate}"/>
<s:DateSpinner id="dt" x="81" y="138" displayMode="{rg.selectedValue}"
               maxDate="{new Date(2011,11,31)}" minDate="{new Date(2011,06,01)}"
               minuteStepSize="10" selectedDate="{new Date(2011,11,31)}"/>
</s:View>
```

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question, not as an external link.  What makes you think the DateSpinner is the problem?

Comment: Hey Jeffry, I included a link to an FXP file via Box.com. The reason I 'know' it's the DateSpinner is when I remove the DateSpinner and only the DateSpinner, the View loads significantly faster. Testing on a PC won't yield any noticeable difference. It needs to be tested on a phone to see the lag. I tested on two phones - Galaxy SII and Galaxy Nexus, both experienced the same lag. Both also showed noticeable improvement once the DS was removed.

Comment: You did link to an FXP via Box.com, however "Please include relevant code in the question, not as an external link."

Comment: Code added to original question

Comment: Did you try your View with a basic DataSpinner, that is no Binding, etc.? I don't have any performance issues with this component on my devices but then again I directly set the DateSpinner's values per AS, not in MXML.